# springboot application fails to start with classnotfoundexception

Tags: spring-boot, pom.xml

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.myapp.interview.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapptestapi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myapptestapi</name>
    <description>Neo4j test project API</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <myapp.version>4.0.2</myapp.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-myapp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.myapp</groupId>
            <artifactId>myapp-bolt</artifactId>
            <version>${myapp.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.myapp</groupId>
            <artifactId>myapp-dbms</artifactId>
            <version>${myapp.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.myapp</groupId>
            <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
            <version>${myapp.version}</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-docs</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <backend>html</backend>
                            <doctype>book</doctype>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-asciidoctor</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-restdocs.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.myapp.interview.api.Neo4jtestApiApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I'm launching the application with `java -jar neo4jtestapi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` or via springboot eclipse plugin or even with `mvn clean install/mvn clean package`

I noted a strange behavior which is when I execute `mvn clean install` or 'mvn package' and then run springboot eclipse plugin, then it fails with the error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.myapp.interview.api.Neo4jtestApiApplication
```

Any idea please ? This is preventing me from launching the application in my EC2 instance now..

Comment: What is the `start-class` property? Where do you use it?

Comment: @Nasir I found it in somewhere in stackoverflow. I'll delete it now. I've already commented it but in vain.

Comment: Can you put all `pom` file content?

Comment: @Nasir : done. Please check

Comment: Can you tell me the result of `mvn -version`?

Comment: Do  you have the same error if you remove `<configuration>
  <mainClass>com.myapp.interview.api.Neo4jtestApiApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>`? from your `pom` file?

Comment: I have same error when commenting mainClass tag. When I clean the project with eclipse menu Project -> Clean, I can execute the springboot class. But If I want to start the application in my EC2 instance, I need to get this fixed :(

Comment: I have noted that the classes I've built are not even in the jar !! That's weird !! The command mvn spring-boot:run fails too